# Bandwidth Consumption on VPN + SSL

Tags: vpn, ssl, bandwidth

I need to estimate how much bandwidth (in Kilobytes) I will consume doing a **https** request (with client ssl authentication) between two servers connected through **VPN** over Internet.

There's no need to be precise (I know it depends on protocols which are still not defined) but I just need a range.

The question: For 1Kb Raw Data (Request and Response) how much HTTP/HTTPS + VPN encapsulation (if there's some encapsulation) will increase data size?